# Carregar DLL (BemaFI32) dinâmica em Delphi

Tags: delphi, dll

Preciso de ajuda em como carregar a DLL `BemaFI32.dll` dinamicamente no Delphi.

Meu código está assim:

```
function _Bematech_FI_NumeroSerie(NumeroSerie: AnsiString): Integer;
var
  xBematech_FI_NumeroSerie : function ( NumeroSerie: AnsiString ): Integer; stdcall;
  lHandle : THandle;
begin
  lHandle := LoadLibrary('bemafi32.dll');
  @xBematech_FI_NumeroSerie := GetProcAddress(lHandle, PChar('Bematech_FI_NumeroSerie'));

  if @xBematech_FI_NumeroSerie = nil then
    raise Exception.Create('Entrypoint Bematech_FI_NumeroSerie não encontrado na Dll');

  Result := xBematech_FI_NumeroSerie(NumeroSerie);
end;
```

O retorno da função é sempre *-4*, indicando que não existe o arquivo `BemaFI32.ini`. Porém o arquivo existe.

Já tentei executar as funções `Bematech_FI_ReloadINIFile` e `Bematech_FI_AbrePortaSerial` antes, porém sempre retorna o mesmo erro.

Estou desenvolvendo em Delphi XE2, em Windows 10 64 bits. Porém também já fiz testes com Windows 7 e o mesmo problema ocorre.

A versão da BemaFi32.dll é 7.0.4.32.

Alguém já teve algum problema semelhante?

Comment: O arquivo `BemaFI32.ini` tem que estar no diretório de sistema do Windows. Tem certeza que ele esta lá?

Comment: @zekk, obrigado pela ajuda.

A dll e o ini estão na mesma pasta do executável. Fiz um teste agora com esses arquivo na pasta do Windows e também não funcionou.
Se eu uso a dll de forma estática, a função executa sem problemas.

Comment: Talvez possa ser um problema com o `UAC`, já tentou executar a aplicação como administrador? dê uma lida também nisso aqui: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/aa384187(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @zekk, 
Seguindo sua dica inicial, coloquei os arquivos na pasta SysWOW64.
Ai funcionou perfeitamente!

Agradeço muito sua ajuda.

Comment: Ronaldo, se você quiser postar isso como resposta, seria de ajuda para outros!

Answer (score 2):

Seguindo a dica do @zekk, eu coloquei o arquivo BemaFi32.ini na pasta C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64.

Dessa forma a comunicação com a DLL funcionou.

Answer (score 1):

fiz a mesma coisa coloquei na pasta SysWOW64,  parece q so acontece isso com Windows 64bit. coloca todas dlls na pasta SysWOW64 q da certo.